# How to retrieve data from text file

Tags: c#

I have data appended line by line in a text file for all confirmed transaction. I want to add Search functionality, where the user enters their E-mail address and all related transaction details connected to that E-mail must be displayed.

```
bool writeNextLine = false;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Read the file and display it line by line.              
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("record.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(txt_SearchBooking.Text))
        {
            // This append the text and a newline into the StringBuilder buffer       
            sb.AppendLine(line.ToString());

            lbl_result.Text += sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

but only the line containing Email is displayed other details are not.

Email is located on the last line of every transaction detail.

```
confirmmsg =
      " Transaction # : " + EmployeeIDTextBox.Text + ClientIDTextBox.Text + UniqueIDTextBox.Text + "\r\n"
    + " First Name : " + ClientFirstNameTextBox.Text + "\r\n"
    + " Telephone Number : " + ClientTelephoneNumberTextBox.Text + "\r\n"
    + " Investment : " + investmentamt.ToString("C2") + "\r\n"
    + " Interest : " + (twelvemonthint * 100).ToString() + "%" + "\r\n"
    + " Interest Amount : " + (invesmentcalc(investmentamt, twelvemonthterm, twelvemonthint) - investmentamt).ToString("C2") + "\r\n"
    + " Bonus : " + bonus.ToString("c2") + "\r\n"
    + " Total Returns : " + invesmentcalc(investmentamt, twelvemonthterm, twelvemonthint).ToString("C2") + "\r\n"
    + " E-mail : " + ClientEmailTextBox.Text;
```

This is the data which is written into the text file.

Comment: Like the name suggests, `ReadLine` reads lines. Your `confirmmsg` contains 9 lines. `ReadLine` reads them one by one. Only the 9th line contains the email address, the first 8 are skipped. There is no connection between the 9th line and the previous 8 lines as far as `ReadLine` is concerned.

Comment: Share the sample text file - Just show how the data is organized in the file.

Comment: Off-topic: good that you use a stringbuilder, but you negate the advantages of that by doing `lbl_result.Text += sb.ToString();` every time. Let your stringbuilder gather everything and _outside_ your loop, just once, do `lbl_result.Text = sb.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

If you always have 9 lines per transaction, with email being the last line, you could use File.ReadAllLines and a counter.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("records.txt");
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
   var line = lines[i];
   if(line.Contains(txt_SearchBooking.Text))
   {
       //Retrieve the previous lines
       for(int y = i-8; y <= i; y++)
       {               
           lbl_result.Text += lines[y];
       }
   }
}
```